# vba, trying to change an opened folder address

Tags: excel, windows, vba, shell, explorer

basically i want to open a windows explorer and navigate through the opened window.
to change the path in the opened window itself.
i figured a way to get the current window path, though its not helping me alot:

```
Set abc = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
for each cell in abc.windows - gives us all the opened windows
 if cell.name = "File Explorer" 'etc
```

and how to open a window:

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="D:\", NewWindow:=True
```

there are more ways to do that, a way to do it in shell:

```
Shell("explorer.exe " & "c:\", vbNormalFocus)
```

basically my whole question is how to change an opened window address, i mean, i can find it as an object with shell.application, how do i continue from here?

also, how do i make an invisible opened explorer?
ty in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control is a `WebBrowser` control.

Add the Microsoft Internet Controls reference library.

For me, it was `Windows Explorer` and not `File Explorer` so I've used this in my code, but if yours is different, just use whatever yours is called.

```
Sub test()
Dim abc As Object
Dim Cell As Variant

Set abc = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each Cell In abc.Windows

    If Cell.Name = "Windows Explorer" Then
        Cell.Navigate "C:\" 'to go to different address
        cell.Visible = True 'to toggle between visible and not  
    End If

Next Cell


End Sub
```

Comment: i tried using it in networked folders and navigate isn't working there... it opens the browser, i'd like to get an alternative, something that is specifically changing the folder current address or something, like a user is able to do.
maybe marking an item and entering it would be also great

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  This code finds the open Windows Explorer window and navigates to "C:\".   Are you saying it won't navigate to, "D:\" for instance?

Comment: no, what i mean is, for example you have a network folder named abc,
to navigate to abc would be fine, but forward would open browsers

Comment: So put the full path of the folder in there: `cell.navigate "G:\mypath\mypath2\abc\"`

Comment: but there is no letter to the network folder, if you put for instance "abc\cde" it'll open a browser.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding.  Where is the folder?  What is the full path of the folder?

Comment: the folder is a network folder, like a ftp defined folder, going there by entering a lnk file, till here everything is good.
when you're in the network folder the command opens the browser instead of changing the folder address.
ps: the url of it is empty, but the path is shown, navigating to a path and not to a url might work, if i'd know how to

Comment: I mean if I put in literally "abc\cde" into windows explorer, it does indeed open up an Internet Explorer window, but I'm guessing that's because it assumes that it is an internet address or something like that.  It is automatically putting "http:\\" in front of it and opening Internet Explorer.

Comment: how to fix it then?

Comment: Or something like that, I haven't really worked with ftp.

Comment: When it opens Internet Explorer, what shows up in the browser bar in internet explorer?  What shows up there when you click on the link in Windows Explorer?

Comment: I think it's probably ftp://

Comment: If I put in the "abc/cde" part the comment is converting it into a link

Comment: a bing search of the navigating name, and ftp at first isn't really solving it... i wonder maybe if i can add some wildcards so that it'll navigate without adding http...

Comment: My guess is that you need to put something first to let it know the type of folder you're opening.  What happens when you put in "ftp://" does it open in Internet Explorer still?

Comment: i tried in explorer, and in explorer ftp isn't working, i dont know exactly if it's a ftp folder, i dont know what type it's exactly.
you can't entering without the lnk to this folder, and while you're in it the other folders above it aren't mentioned in the address.

Comment: Where did the link come from?  What happens if you right-click the link and choose properties?  What information is in there?

Comment: What is the target of the link?

Comment: the target is its name, so basically it has no target (no drive letter or whatsoever).
it's a file from a software, that opens a folder, i wonder if there're like symbols that may be used in any folder in windows explorer and won't change a thing (at the beginning of it)
 also it might not be polite, but i can show it to you if you'd want, in skype's (mtnjustme) screenshare or facebook (matan yashar) also thanks for your time and help

Comment: What kind of a file is it?  What is the extension?

Comment: I can't really do that.  What happens when you click on the link.  What shows up in the Windows Explorer area then?

Comment: What shows up in the Internet Explorer address bar when you open it in Internet Explorer?

Comment: its name, the folder is basically the software, i mean, there are folders and files inside, but it has no destination written in the address, except the software's destinations.
for example, the first folder will be its name, the second will be the firstname\secondname, etc.
the extension is lnk.
it shows the path i wanted to navigate to as a bing search

Comment: What happens if you right click on the lnk file then choose the shortcut tab?  What is in the Target section?

Comment: its name.
also i tried a thing, i typed http://etc
and it didn't do a bing search, but opened http://etc as a site.

Comment: I don't think I can help with this then.  Sorry.

Comment: You could try adding the name of the software into the question and maybe someone knows something about it.

Comment: well ty for your help and time... i appreciate it alot :)
i think i'll figure something out maybe... for now getting tired, need to sleep i suppose.
have a good night/day there and ty again for the help.

Comment: Try in the format `\\servername\foldername\ ` so if your server is `abc` and your folder is `cde` then try navigating to `\\abc\cde\ ` This is called a UNC path and Windows Explorer should open to the network folder if it can get to it.

Comment: watch this thread if you may:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394372/vba-programming-create-shortcut-to-file-on-xbox-360-neighborhood?noredirect=1#comment64201346_38394372